# Java: Using method in another class

Tags: java, class, methods

I am trying to use the String returned by this method in another class.
This is the method:

```
public String toString(){ return String.format("(%f, %f, %f)",longitude, latitude, elevation);}
```

This is the other class method:

```
void addPoint(){
  coordinates.add(Point.toSting);
}
```

I know that I could create an object, but neither of these classes has a main method.

Comment: Put all code from your *another class* and *other class* because problem is not clear.

Comment: A program may create millions of point objects when it runs, or none. Which of them should that method in "the other class" use?

Comment: (1) If this is Java code, then calling methods with 0 arguments requires putting braces after the method's name, like this: `point.toString()`.
(2) Probably there is no static 'toString' method for the `Point` class, so you should call the method on behalf of some object.
(3) Are you using a decent IDE like Eclipse or IntelliJ? I'm sure it'd help you a lot, as it'd indicate problems with syntax, explain some errors etc.

Comment: If my answer fixes your problem I would be grateful if you click the tick next to my answer (top left) to show others that question has been answered sufficiently and to let the author of the question (me) know that their answer was correct.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this?

**Your Main Class which runs everything**

```
public class Test {
    private void run() {
        new Test2();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test t = new Test();
        t.run();
    }
}
```

**Some Class which gets string from another class**

```
public class Test2 {
    private void displayString() {
        System.out.println(new Test3().toString());
    }

    Test2() {
        displayString();
    }
}
```

**Final Class which contains String**

```
public class Test3 {
    public String toString() {
        return "Hi";
    }

    Test3() {

    }
}
```